# HTTPS Proxy - Is it possible to proxy a HTTPS request without having certificates setup?

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, https, certificate

HTTPS Proxy - Is it possible to proxy a HTTPS request without having certificates setup?

In my case I'm still trying to workout how to do this with .NET HttpListener & HttpWebRequest.  I've got it working for HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will you be able to configure a proxy on the client?  If a proxy is configured the client will use an [HTTP CONNECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_Tunnelling) to access https sites.  No certificates need to be setup on the proxy.

If you are trying to setup an interception cache (transparent) then you pretty much have to setup certificates and get the clients to trust them.

Comment: so the proxy I have in mind is one where I would have to manually point my applications to it (e.g. for browser set the host/port for my home grown proxy) - so this is not a transparent proxy correct?